# How to force chrony to sync NOW?

Tags: cron, systemd, ntp, chrony

I run a DB cluster that needs to be in time. Sadly, sometimes my VM hoster is moving the VM with such DB node to another host and then the time is lacking a second or more. My DB node then shuts down and is restarted by systemd.

My systemd file contains this:

```
ExecStartPre=-+/usr/bin/chronyc -a makestep
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/.......
```

I expected this to sync my time immediately after such time lag shut down the database. But due to my logs **it took up to 7 minutes until the difference was recognized and fixed**. My database detected the gap on every restart and shut down again. Finally, I get this chronyd log:

```
Nov 16 10:25:51 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by 0.000020 seconds
Nov 16 10:26:07 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:26:23 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:26:39 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:26:55 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:27:11 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:27:27 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:27:43 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:27:59 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:28:15 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:28:31 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:28:47 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:28:59 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: Source 81.169.199.94 replaced with 212.71.244.243
Nov 16 10:29:03 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:29:19 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:29:32 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: Selected source 109.230.227.90
Nov 16 10:29:35 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by 0.003850 seconds
Nov 16 10:29:51 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:30:07 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:30:23 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:30:39 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:30:55 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:31:11 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:31:27 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:31:43 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:31:59 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:32:13 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: Can't synchronise: no majority
Nov 16 10:32:15 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:32:31 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:32:33 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: Selected source 109.230.227.90
Nov 16 10:32:33 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock wrong by 1.101260 seconds, adjustment started
Nov 16 10:32:48 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by 1.003151 seconds
Nov 16 10:33:04 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:33:21 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:33:37 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by -0.000000 seconds
Nov 16 10:33:51 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: Selected source 162.159.200.123
Nov 16 10:33:53 dc3-sirius chronyd[164166]: System clock was stepped by 0.409613 seconds
```

As you can see, it started to sync the clock after >7 minutes:

My DB detected the issue at 10:25:51. From this, the above command was executed several times to re-sync the clock before every database restart. But it needed until 10:32:33 and 10:33:53 to really finally fix the clock.

Any idea how I can force the clock to get synchronized directly and not many minutes later?

Comment: I currently try it with the value "makestep 0.4 -1" in chrony.conf. Not sure if this will solve my issue. Now I have to wait until my hoster moves the VM again...

Comment: The updated chrony.conf did not help. It took 10 minutes with several calls to detect the time lag and force the new sync. Any other ways to force sync????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution to keep chrony and also force an immediate time sync in case of a time lag (detected by the DB node). The solution was to restart the chronyd service - simulating a reboot of the system.

I changed my systemd file of the database to look like this:

```
ExecStartPre=-+systemctl restart chronyd
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cockroach start ...
```

In the `/etc/chrony.conf` file I added the lines:

```
initstepslew 0.5 pool.ntp.org
makestep 0.5 -1
```

This forces chronyd to re-sync the time on a restart if the time offset is bigger than 0.5 seconds.

This finally makes my system re-sync directly and then restart the database node immediately.

You can look [here](https://chrony-project.org/doc/4.4/chrony.conf.html) to find more information about the chrony.conf options.